# Ignore CGFloat type warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

I've got a function with such part of code:

```
if (CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE) {
    return fabs(x / y);
} else {
    return fabsf(x / y);
}
```

However with new Xcode I'm obtaining a warning here:

> Absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'double' but
>   has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value

The warning wasn't visible in `Xcode 6`, but in `Xcode 7 Beta` it is.

With such wrapping, I'm moreover sure that the values are `float` type. Now the question is how to suppress the warning?

I've tried with many `Clang` flags, ended on most general:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
    // above code
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But it doesn't help (odd?). `"-W"` also doesn't help. Any tip..?

**I don't want to cast, create extra float variables nor anything similar. I just want to silence the warning.**

Comment: OK, so what sets `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Core Graphics.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like it's lying?  The issue is not to suppress the warning but to find the condition necessary to call the right version of `fabs()`, as you have so far.  I would find out why Core Graphics is lying to you.  Or perhaps you haven't imported the right header files when that macro is referenced (another possibility).

Comment: @trojanfoe Core Graphics is lying? I can't agree with your way of thinking. If you don't know these statements you may visit the header and check it out. The flag is just a macro and compiler may not know it have been checked, so it sets the warning. Everything is working correctly. The condition is proper, as this flag is used to vary CGFloat implementations.

Comment: Are you certain the Core Graphics header file is included at the time that statement is evaluated?

Comment: @trojanfoe Otherwise the compiler would not know what is `CGFloat` as this is where the definition of `CGFloat` is ;) So yes, I'm sure.

Comment: I see your point.  Well either the Core Graphics header file is lying, the compiler is lying or you are no longer using the right conditions to detect `CGFloat == double`.

Comment: @trojanfoe `CoreGraphics - CGBase.h` and inside firstly: `#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double (...)` then `typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;`. This is not the cause, everything is working correctly, the debugger isn't aware that i'm sure of the type. The conditions are right, as it would be stated somewhere otherwise. I still have the issue with suppressing the warning, as I can't 'fix' the compiler, so it doesn't matter for me if it's lying or not.

Comment: @trojanfoe neither the compiler nor the CoreGraphics headers are lying; the compiler complains about `fabsf()` because it's **still** in the code (albeit unreachable). The if statement presented here is not a compile-time check, it's a runtime check.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Using `#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` would solve the issue; I missed that completely.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, but it's a bit inconvenient to use. I'm still looking for a way to suppress that warning wit Clang.

Comment: Then you probably want to suppress `-Wabsolute-value`.  I think that's a mistake, however.  You can make the call to the right version of `fabs()` more convenient using an inline function or macro.

Comment: @trojanfoe That's how I'm doing it. Still inside inline function I have to vary which version is `double` and which is `float` for `CGFloat`, unless I misunderstood your words. Why does `-Wabsolute-value` work when `"-Wall"`/`-W` doesn't..?

Comment: I'm not even sure it will work.  As I've said I wouldn't go down that path as for every warning that's suppressed a puppy dies.

Comment: @trojanfoe Hm... Well, maybe in fact the solution with `#if` will be better than silencing the warning. Please post it as an answer with `-Wabsolute-value`, as one is the better method and other one is direct answer for question, so it may be useful by someone who comes here to check it. I will accept the answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe Please post your comment(s) as an answer so I can accept it.